# How to combine data not of the same 'grain' and in separate data sources as an aggregated rate in Tableau

Tags: sql, analytics, tableau-api

In Tableau 10.3, I have two tables (derived from SQL queries): Return Reasons, which has one row per day + city + return reason, and 'Sales' has one row per day + city (and NOT by return reason, since obviously not all sales are returned.)

I have two rows in Return Reasons for 2017-10-01 in Seattle: $10 in returns for 'Bad Fit' and $20 in returns for 'Poor Quality'. The Sales table has a row for 2017-10-01 in Seattle with $1000.
I want to show a graph with, say, a stacked bar giving $10/$1000 (1% rate) for Bad Fit stacked with $20/$1000 (2% rate) for Poor Quality. I can graph the $10 and $20 separate from the $1000 of sales, but combining to get the rates has stumped me. Importantly, I don't just want to aggregate by day + city, but might also roll up by month (from day) and country (from city.)

Short of creating columns for each return reason, which isn't scalable (due to any number of reasons which could change at any time), any idea how to do this?

Duplicating Sales across the reason rows didn't seem to help me. (E.g.: I could add columns Sales to Return Reasons, JOINing on day + city, giving $1000 (duplicated) in each row. This would be fine if I only aggregated at the city + day level, but I want to aggregate both Sales + Reasons by month, country, etc.)

Comment: It sounds like most of your columns are the same for both sets.  My recommendation would be to union the data sets and not join.  You could then create an additional column indicating whether it was a sale or a return.  That should allow you to perform aggregations at different levels referencing both return and sales data.  Your return reason for Sales could just be NULL or "Sales", something like that.

Comment: You have options with different pros and cons. Two features to investigate are LOD calcs and data blending. Both are towards the more advanced trickier end of the spectrum of Tableau features, but both are very useful for particular kinds of problems. If you join your 2 tables, LOD calcs could help you manage any duplicate data issues. If you are really just combining aggregated data, then data blending may fit the bill